# Android Studio gets laggy when typing. Diagnosing tips?

Tags: android-studio, android-studio-3.3

This started happening recently. The CPU usage is <5% when idle, but as soon as I start typing goes to **100%**. I tried many of the proposed speed ups I found on other questions but none worked. My question is: what is the best way to know what is taking up so many CPU resources? Is there a way to know which plugin is using those resources? Is there a log one can look into?

Comment: What kind of storage system are you using HDD or SSD?

Comment: SDD. To clarify, this just started happening a few days ago. Before that it was running smoothly.

Comment: Is it happening on the emulator or on your device?

Comment: The actual editor gets laggy, not the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couldn't find a solution to this. Reinstalling Android Studio without using the previous configuration solved the problem.